# css / header pushing two (absolutely positioned) stretched columns down

Tags: css

After some hours of fiddling I thought I’d try my luck over here. I’m working on a website design which has quite a basic setup, it consists out of a header and two columns, which have their own scrollbars. This requires their position to be absolute, and to have a top value set, and a bottom value of 0px. This ofcourse prevents them from being in the normal document flow, and therefore they cant be pushed down by the header column.

Any ideas on how to achieve this with css only are most welcome, it seems so straightforward!

Best regards,
Thijs.

Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Testcase</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    background-color: #c8ffff;

}

#lr_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#leftcol {
    background-color: #ffdcff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#rightcol {
    background-color: #ffffd1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
variable amount of content, needs to stretch in height and push the pink and yellow kids downwards<br/><br/>!<br/>!<br/><br/>!<br/>!<br/><br/>!<br/>!<br/><br/>!<br/>!
</div>

<div id="lr_container">

    <div id="leftcol">

    has a fixed width, stretches to the bottom of window<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>
    aa<br/><br/>

    </div>

    <div id="rightcol">
    stretches to the right and stretches to the bottom of window<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    bb<br/><br/>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

http://www.thingsinprogress.net/test.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would solve it:

```
#leftcol {
  background-color:#FFDCFF;
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  left:0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
}
#rightcol {
  background-color:#FFFFD1;
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  left:200px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:relative;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

Now the both columns, leftcol and rightcol, will be pushed downwards if the content grows.
You can clear the float with clear: both;

```
<div id="leftcol">col1</div>
<div id="rightcol">col2</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, the thing is though that the columns need to stretch to the bottom of the viewport and have their own individual scrollbars, so that they can only scroll individually, and not the page as a whole. Therefore they can’t have their height attribute set I think. Do you have another suggestion? Thanks alot!